# Regex expression doesn't remove only one character words

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like my regex replace remove all ' longdesc="anything" ' in my HTML.

So, now I'm using this expression:

```
   const cleanHTML = dirtyHTML
    .replace(/longdesc="[a-zA-Z0-9:;.s()-, ]*"/g, '') // to clean anything beetween "" 
    .replace(/longdesc/g, '') // to clean longdec's
```

And this expression doesn't work.

Comment: `.replace(/\s+longdesc(?:="[^"]*")?/g, '')`? Note it will remove more than attributes, it will remove it in text, too. That is why you must use an HTML parser.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work?" Can you give an example input string and expected output string, and what your current solution results in?

Comment: Wiktor (first comment) solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the string is not parsed, so or I use a HTML Parser, and my code will work, or use `.replace(/\s+longdesc(?:="[^"]*")?/g, '')` that works with HTML not parsed.